# bus can't be started twice with version 2.6

Tags: .net, nservicebus

When we upgraded from version 2.5 of NServiceBus to version 2.6, we discovered a change of behavior. In version 2.5 we could create a bus multiple times but in version 2.6 the `CreateBus()` returned `null` after the second time of invocation. 
Can anyone explain why?

I have read the release notes and can’t find anything about this change of behavior.
The code below will reproduce the behavior if you try it with these two versions of NServiceBus.

```
        var busStartable = NServiceBus.Configure.With().Log4Net()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .MsmqTransport()
           .UnicastBus()
           .CreateBus();

        var bus = busStartable.Start();

        var busStartable2 = NServiceBus.Configure.With().Log4Net()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .MsmqTransport()
           .UnicastBus()
           .CreateBus(); // returns null with 2.6

        var bus2 = busStartable2.Start(); //  Object reference not set to ….
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two bus objects in the same app domain isn't supported. I'm not sure why this worked in version 2.5 but it shouldn't have :)